# Is there a way for a jqm slider element to work in 2 ways (leftward rand rightward), witha central value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, slider

I am trying to get a jqm slider element to work as a "pan" command on an amplifier, so that:

- range is from minus a certain value, to a certain value (achieved by "min="-50" max="50"" );
- be loaded in central postion, correspnding to zero (achieved by "value=0")
- slider background is not present when at zero value, but is materialized only form center (0 value) to the handle when moved leftward/rightward  (still open issue)

Any clue how to do so, if possible ?

Thanks you.
Janko.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

Given the standard slider markup with min max and initial value set as you specified:

```
<label for="pan">Pan:</label>
<input type="range" name="pan" id="pan" min="-50" max="50" value="0" />
```

On pagecreate, insert a relatively positioned DIV into the slider track and then set its dimensions on the change event of the slider:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){

    var colorback  = '<div class="sliderBackColor"></div>'
    $( "#pan" ).closest(".ui-slider").find(".ui-slider-track").prepend(colorback);


    $("#pan").on("change", function(){
        var v = parseInt($(this).val());
        var $highlight = $(this).closest(".ui-slider").find(".sliderBackColor");
        var l = v + 50;
        var w = Math.abs(v);
        if (v > 0){
            l = 50;            
        } 
        $highlight.css({"left": l + "%",  "width": w + "%"});
    });

});
```

The CSS for the highlight makes sure the DIV uses relative positioning, sets the height to 100% of the track, sets the background color and initializes the width to 0;

```
.sliderBackColor {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%; 
    background-color: #8A9B0F;
}
```

Each time the slider changes value, we calculate the new left position and width of the highlight to keep one end at 50% and the other at the current value. So for negative values the left is set to the negative value plus 50%; whereas for positive values the left is pegged at 50%. The width is then the absolute value of the current value.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rrs42bn3/1/)**

If you are using a jQM version earlier than 1.4, change pagecreate to pageinit and the same solution should work:

> **[1.3 DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rrs42bn3/2/)**

Also, see this article for other interesting things you can do with the slider:

http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/fun-with-the-slider-widget/

For example, you could change the highlight color as the pan gets further away from center:

> **[Color Change Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rrs42bn3/3/)**